# Bootstrap 5 Modal Doesn't Show with Fade Class

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

When I add the fade class to my Bootstrap 5 modal, it doesn't show. If I remove the class, the dialog shows but the body isn't greyed out nor does the modal animate. My HTML is:

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="forgot_block" aria-labelledby="label-forgot_block" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog " style="border-radius: 10px;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header ui-widget-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="label-forgot_block">Forgot Password</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <b>Please enter your email address below and a new temporary password will be sent to you.</b>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <input type="text" name="current_email" id="current_email" placeholder="email address" size="40" onkeyup="checkKey(event,'sendPassword_exec'">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div id="dialog_alert-forgot_block">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="dialog_buttons_box-forgot_block"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To show the modal, my JS code is:

```
var modal = $("#forgot_block").modal();
modal.show();
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have combined Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5 syntax. You have to decide:

Bootstrap 4 syntax:

```
var modal = $("#forgot_block").modal()
modal.modal('show');
```

Bootstrap 5 syntax:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('forgot_block'))
myModal.show();
```

Maybe I should have written jQuery and vanilla JS syntax, but you get the point.

Also, in your code you are missing 1 parenthesis in checkKey call between closing quotation marks'", it should be onkeyup="checkKey(event,'sendPassword_exec')"

After these changes the code works for me - modal fades in from top of the screen

Comment: Works great and thanks for spotting my missing closing parenthesis!